# Form won't recognize custom input directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a system to dynamically generate forms.  I created a directive that, from an input id, looks up metadata about an input field and generates the template for that field.  The input works fine, however the form doesn't recognize that it exists.  It doesn't factor in to the calculation of form.$valid, etc.  What mystical thing is happening between compile and link, that makes the form recognize an input?

Here's the simplified code:
See this in action on: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dYA1KAXnonBEaQpCh37O?p=preview)

```
<form name="myForm">
  works: <input type="text" ng-model="model.works" required></input>
  <div ng-repeat="inp in inputList">
      broken: <my-component info="inp"></my-component>
  </div>
  form valid: {{myForm.$valid}}
</form>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    works:'works',
    broken:'broken',
  };
  $scope.inputList = [
    {id:'broken'},
  ];
});

app.directive('myComponent', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        'info': '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var html = '<input type="text" ng-model="model.'+ $scope.info.id +'" required></input>';
        $scope = $scope.$parent.$parent;
          // ^ this hack makes the model work, but form still not attached
        var el = $compile(html)($scope);
        $element.replaceWith(el);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The mystical thing you're thinking of is "Scope".  AngularJS "Scope" is what glues the models, views and controllers together.  In your posted code there are 3 different scopes to be considered.  The "MainCtrl" scope.  We'll call this 'scope01'.  The "ng-repeat" creates a new scope for each iteration.  We'll call this 'scope02' since you only have one item in your array.  Finally, your directive has an [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).  We'll call it 'scope03'.

Variables in your directive will need to traverse two scopes to get back to your "MainCtrl" controller scope01.  This is why your hack requires two "$parent" calls.  "myForm" object resides in 'scope01'.  It will be inherited by 'scope02' but will need to be passed into 'scope03'.  You'll need to bubble up changes to 'scope01' via double binding the parameter or using events to "broadcast" the changes to the input.

Here's an example using a parameter and double binding:

```
<my-component info="inp" form-ref="myForm">
```

In your directive:

```
var directive = {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
  'info': '=',
  'formRef': '='
},
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  //You may want to wrap the following  in a watch:
  formRef.$valid = myService.isValid(scope.info);// myService checks if input is valid and returns true or false
}
};
```

Comment: Won't this have each input overwriting form.$valid?

Comment: Yes, I was mostly just showing an example of how to communicate between the scopes.  You have access to the form object.  How and what you do with that access is up to you.  There are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in case anyone else runs into this:

```
    var el = $compile(html)($scope.$parent, function(_el) {
      $element.replaceWith(_el);
    });
```

Updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5qX3wzyZQ6XpCB7cYWRf?p=info)